# Ansible loop over list extracted from dict

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible 2.9 on RHEL 7.7, and I'm trying to loop over a list which is a value from a dict element. So far I have this var file and play:

```yaml
ssh_keys:
  account: blah
  permissions: 600
  keys:
    - qa-publickeys['1']
    - qa-publickeys['2']
    - qa-publickeys['3']
```

the play:

```yaml
- name: Traversing ssh keys 
  debug:
    msg: "Here's: {{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ ['keys'] | map('extract', ssh_keys) | list }}"
```

The problem is, `msg` is `"msg": "Here's: [u\"qa-publickeys['1']\", u\"qa-publickeys['2']\", u\"qa-publickeys['3']\"]"`

Why is it not giving me three outputs, with `Here's: qa-publickeys['1']` as the first output, `Here's: qa-publickeys['2']` as the second, and finally `Here's: qa-publickeys['3']` ?

The list that I present to the `loop` in this play is not getting looped over, it's just iterating once in one chunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to make is really complex for yourself for no apparent reason.
A dictionary in Ansible can be accessed via either the `.` dot notation or the `[]` square brackets notation.

Now because [`.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) is indeed a built-in method of a dictionary in Python, you cannot use the first notation, but you can use the later one.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Here's: {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ ssh_keys['keys'] }}"
      vars:
        ssh_keys:
          account: blah
          permissions: 600
          keys:
            - qa-publickeys['1']
            - qa-publickeys['2']
            - qa-publickeys['3']
```

This yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=qa-publickeys['1']) => 
  msg: 'Here''s: qa-publickeys[''1'']'
ok: [localhost] => (item=qa-publickeys['2']) => 
  msg: 'Here''s: qa-publickeys[''2'']'
ok: [localhost] => (item=qa-publickeys['3']) => 
  msg: 'Here''s: qa-publickeys[''3'']'

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```